# How to change email sender depending on order total in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce

I would like to change email sender, depending on order total value.

Example:

- if order total > 100, use bigaccount@sender.com
- otherwise, use regularaccount@sender.com

I cant figure out how to get $order dealing with email sender.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order' filter hook([Check here](https://www.mootpoint.org/blog/customising-woocommerce-notification-emails-hooks-filters/)) to change sender email
Please check below code you can get basic idea,

```
function wc_change_admin_new_order_email_recipient( $recipient, $order ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    if ( $order->get_total() > 100 ) { // Set your condition here and dump to know more about $order
        $recipient = "bigaccount@sender.com";
    } else {
        $recipient = "regularaccount@sender.com";
    }
    return $recipient;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'wc_change_admin_new_order_email_recipient', 1, 2);
```